# Orange tree has pest or blight

Tags: pest-control, citrus, pest-damage, blight

A few leaves on my orange tree have this.

[image: cottony scale]

[image: cottony scale 2]

What is this?
What can I do about it?

Comment: My first guess is that it's some kind of scale - maybe cottony cushion.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate because the target contains more information.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ed that this is most likely to be a cottony [mealybug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug).

- You can control this taking a paper towel soaked in dish soap and water and wiping the leaves down.
- Repeat for every leaf with the symptoms. Check the axils where the leaves join the stems too.
- After the treatment rinse or spray with water to prevent a soapy buildup
- repeat every five to seven days for at least three times
- continue to monitor as mealybug is hard to get rid of
- move the tree away from any other houseplants.  Some adult mealybugs have wings and fly to spread the population.
- check for other plants that may have it too

Comment: Tks guys, this is a help.