# Why is my hibiscus shriveling, losing buds, and having other problems?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, hibiscus

My hibiscus has white stuff around the buds. The green leaves are small and shriveled and the buds dry and fall off before they even open. How do I correct this and stop it from going to my other plants?

Comment: Can you add a photograph of the problem please, and say what part of the world you're in. Is this plant in the ground or in a pot?

Comment: Welcome to the group!  As suggested, more information would be helpful to pin point the problem.  Information about your location, weather conditions, can have an impact on how people respond as well

Comment: White stuff is a bit vague... again photo needed. A wild guess would be that it's been frost damaged. Knowing where you are growing it (both where in the world and inside/outside) would also be help.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [previous question and answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/what-is-the-white-substance-on-my-hibiscus) that could be very similar to your issue (although not necessarily).

The small leaves and buds that fail indicate that they are not getting enough nutrient to perform their function properly. One reason could be that bugs are drinking the sap before they can benefit from it, and @kevinsky response in the other question will help you a lot. Examine the white stuff on your plant carefully and see if it is hiding anything. Houseplant and other gardeners can benefit a great deal from a magnifying glass to see small critters and possible eggs, and a lot of practice examining various plants and bugs up close. Get as much experience as you can.