# What are those white spots? Are they mould & harmful?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, houseplants, indoors, diseases

I have an indoor plant located at the windows of my kitchen.

I water it every 2-3 days with rice water and the plant has been growing well.

Recently I spotted some white spot at the soil of the plant.
Could they be mould? Are they harmful? If yes, how do I get rid of them?

Unfortunately, I do not know the name of the plant. My best guess is succulent. So here are the images:
[image: zoom-out actual plant]
[image: white spot]

Thank you.

Comment: @GardenGems no answers in comments, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plant is a Jade Plant (*Crassula ovata*)... with Sphagnum moss growing below it... generally Jade Plants want to be fairly dry, and Sphagnum moss grows in bogs... I think you are probably overwatering it... as for the white stuff on the moss... probably fungal... could also be some sort of arthropod pest though (can't see in the photo.)

Answer (score 0):

Grady Player is right that the plant is a Jade Plant and they like dry soil and lots of sunlight.  The white spots seems to be on the plant and the moss which makes me think they are mealybug.
Your test is to get a toothpick and a magnifying glass.  If you can pick a white spot off the plant with the toothpick and it moves then it's mealy bug.

You can find more details [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/19655/499) and treatment  [here](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/GARDEN/PLANTS/INVERT/mealybugs.html)

Definitely remove the moss as that is just another place for the bugs to hide.