# How to save Jade Plant (Crassula ovata) from dropping more leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, diagnosis, succulents, jade

I need advice from you all to save this Jade Plant (Crassula ovata).

4 months ago, it looked healthy with big fat, plump leaves from this image here [image: Healthy leaves] - taken from my other question [What are those white spots? Are they mould & harmful?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/what-are-those-white-spots-are-they-mould-harmful)

Now the plant has been dropping leaves and the older leaves look wrinkle and weak.
[image: wrinkle leaves #1] [image: wrinkle leaves #2]

I also notice there is a white spot at the branches at the bottom
[image: white spot]

I have inspected the root of the plant. There is no smell here.
[image: root]

Currently, I water the plant every other 2 days and the situation does not improve.
The plant has a lot of sunlight from morning where sun rises until after noon hour where the sun moves to other direction
[image: current location with sun]

Here is another top view of the plant with the soil condition:
[image]

1. Should I increase the water frequency?
2. Should I move the plant to more sunny place?
3. Has the plant got disease?
4. How do I save this plant? ='(
5. Should I sit this plant in a pool of water?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should repot it into a larger pot with drainage holes (1, at most 2 sizes up) removing the mossy stuff at the top as you do it by pulling it all off, including some of the soil attached to it, without damaging the roots of the Jade plant.  Use fresh potting soil to pack round the rootball and keep the soil level the same as it is now up the stems.  More soil round the root ball means it will hang on to water for a little longer  because the soil is not solid with roots, and have room to put out new roots and hopefully more, healthier growth.

In terms of watering, that mossy stuff indicates the soil is compacted and is not draining very well, another reason to repot. The best way to water is water the plant in immediately after repotting, allowing excess water to drain away freely from the base prior to placing it back in an outer pot or saucer. Ongoing, water when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, water well, again allowing excess to drain away freely, and make sure you empty the outer pot or tray 30 minutes after watering so the plant is not left sitting in water.

I can't see a 'white spot' on the base of any stem - just a strip of somewhat paler bark which may have been caused by the moss/lichen growth keeping it damp at times, but is nothing to worry about.

Comment: thank you for the advice. My new pot delivery is 2 weeks away. While waiting for the new pot, what can I do to improve the jade plant meanwhile? 

Should I face the plant to more sunny or shady area? Can I water every 3 days? Thank you.

Comment: Water when it needs it -if that;s very two days, stick to  that, if its three, do that. It gets sun currently and that will mean about the same amount of water probably as its been getting. just try to keep it going till you can repot, not much else you can do.