# What are these bugs on my lemon tree?

Tags: bugs, lemons

I've noticed some white bugs on my potted lemon tree and would like to know what they are,  and advice on how to kill them!

Any help is greatly appreciated -

Aaron.

[image: bug on lemon tree]

Answer (score 1):

These are [mealybug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug) and getting rid of them takes a bit of work. The process is described [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/4571/499).  You can resolve this with soap and water but the key is wiping the plant down to crush any eggs and juveniles and repeating the process every five to seven days to get the eggs as they hatch.

The warmer is is the faster they reproduce do don't delay!